# Android Int String Value

Tags: java, android, string

I am trying to create a android version of cookie clickers called bitcoin minter as my first project and i am having trobules changing the value of the number of coins you have. My code so far is below

```
public void addcoins(View view) {
    int numofcoins = 3;
    TextView textElement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myAwesomeTextView);
    numofcoins = numofcoins + 1;
    textElement.setText(numofcoins);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
textElement.setText(""+numofcoins);
```

Comment: I Specifically need it to add 1 to the number of coins whenever the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert the integer to a string:

```
textElement.setText(Integer.toString(numofcoins));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textElement.setText(String.valueOf(numofcoins));
```